# Need Jersey2 technique to enable or disable services during runtime

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am looking for a way to configure during runtime (say, via a properties file, or deployment descriptor) which services in my Jersey-based application are available, i.e. so that services can be enabled or disabled by an administrator at the container level.

Our app presently exposes 15 different endpoints. It has 1 Application annotated with @ApplicationPath with 3 classes annotated with @Path, and within those 3 classes are 15 different methods annotated with the usual @Path/@/@Produces.
 
My app has a few different techniques for reading its runtime configuration, e.g. settings to connect to database resources, watching a properties file for changes, etc. What I want to do is add some configuration values so that administrators can enable/disable the 3 classes or any of the individual endpoints within those classes at the Jersey level. Could someone suggest the best way to do this?
 
Taking that a step further, we want to control this configuration in runtime, so if the configuration changes, we can update the jersey configuration to enable/disable the changed services without having to restart our container (which is Tomcat in this case).
 
Any advice appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible natively with Jersey, but one thing I can think of is to just use a Jersey prematching filter to determine if the endpoints are disabled. You can use a service that can also act as a listener and update the disabled endpoints accordingly. If the endpoint is disabled, then just return a 404.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class DisabledEndpointsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    private ConfigurationService configuration;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        final List<String> disabledEndpoints = this.configuration.getDisabledEndpoints();
        final String path = stripLeadingSlash(request.getUriInfo().getPath());

        for (String endpoint: disabledEndpoints) {
            endpoint = stripLeadingSlash(endpoint);
            if (path.startsWith(endpoint)) {
                request.abortWith(Response.status(404).build());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was playing around with this and put together a working POC. You can checkout the [Github Repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-disable-endpoint).

Comment: I like that! Its simple and isn't a hack. I hadn't explored this capability of Jersey, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use apache camel for this. With camel you can control the http requests combined with a embedded jetty server as proxy.

http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html